# Android app crashes during changing views

Tags: android, crash, titanium-mobile

I am creating an android app in titanium. When I navigate to the 4th screen from the 3rd screen of the app, an alert appears stating that the application has closed unexpectedly with a button of forced closed.

I have changed the ordering of screens, but this did not resolve my issue.

Please help me out in this regard - I am new to android development.

Comment: You need to give way more information.

Comment: give some code snippet where error is occuring or send your log cat details for error

Comment: which type of more information, i mean what you want to ask?

Comment: actually error is occuring when i go from 3rd screen to 4th screen. i have change the navigation ordering and make 4th screen to 3rd in order and 5th to 4th but still having same error.

Comment: without looking at the code or error details we can't do anything

Comment: Ok, let me send you error from consol

Comment: I/ActivityManager(   60): Process com.domainname.divemanagerprofile (pid 315) has died.
I/WindowManager(   60): WIN DEATH: Window{440cb098 com.domainname.divemanagerprofile/com.domainname.divemanagerprofile.Test_appActivity paused=false}
W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{440c2c90 com.domainname.divemanagerprofile/.Test_appActivity}

Comment: Thanks all, my problem is resolved now, by disabling the fast development property.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the activity to the manifest file?